# Trigger don't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help here :)

```
 DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER update_tab2 AFTER INSERT ON contacts
        FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN
                IF(NEW.city= 'LA') THEN
                    SET  NEW.tag = "HI LA";
                END IF;
            END;
     |
    DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger should update me the tag column when the user complete a html "city" form with LA. The trigger is correct (the syntax I mean, but just don't put anything in the "tag" column.

Can anyone give me a hint about what is wrong? :)

Comment: As Gordon says... before insert is your solution. After insert triggers are used to maybe update other tables. I also suggest you test your triggers directly with PHPMyAdmin or some other interactive tool, before trying them out from within your application.

Comment: Yup, I guess that is the solution for the trigger, but in my app is broking my html form that is sending data to DB.

Comment: If your app has problems sending data to the back-end... that's a whole different problem, and deserves a whole different question on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You need a *before insert* trigger if you want to change the data being inserted:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER update_tab2 BEFORE INSERT ON contacts
    FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            IF(NEW.city = 'LA') THEN
                SET  NEW.tag = "HI LA";
            END IF;
        END;
 |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The problem with doing it BEFORE is that I guess that this is creating a conflict with the INSERT from that form. After creating this trigger, when I submit the form just don't insert me anything in DB.

Comment: @user140102 . . . I am guessing that you have other problems not related to this trigger.